# How to create an ARRAYFORMULA that SUM multiple columns that are not next to each other

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Kind people smarter than myself: 
I want to convert this formula in Google Sheets:

=SUM(L3:O3,R3:U3)

into an array formula for rows 3 - 24. Any help or suggestions appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what technology you're asking about. That will get it to the right people who can answer it.

Comment: Are you talking about Excel? If you do, please add this information on your question and add the correct tags to the question.

Comment: fair point! done, thanks

Answer (score 0):

An array formula is created by entering the formula and then using

ctrl + shift + enter

Does this formula work for you:

```
{=SUM(L3:O24,R3:U24)}
```

You'll notice than an array formula will automatically add the {} to the front and back of the formula.

Comment: it doesn't my friend - I have got a number of array formulas in my doc (including this beauty that works:

=ARRAYFORMULA(((ARRAYFORMULA(IF(J3:J24="","",(ArrayFormula(vlookup($A3:$A24&J3:J24, {LeaCalcs!$A$3:$A&LeaCalcs!$B$3:$B, LeaCalcs!$C$3:$J}, 2, 0 ))))))*(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(K3:K24="","",(ArrayFormula(vlookup($A3:$A24&J3:J24, {LeaCalcs!$A$3:$A&LeaCalcs!$B$3:$B, LeaCalcs!$C$3:$J}, 5, 0 )))))))*(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(K3:K24="","",(VLOOKUP(K3:K24,PraCalcs!$A$3:$E$7,2,false))))))

I just can't seem to find an elegant solution to something I feel must be simple

Answer (score 0):

Use `+`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(L3:O3+R3:U3)
```

or

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(L3:O24+R3:U24)
```